# How to merge 2 arrays with n elements into 1 array with n objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to do something like this:

```
const foo = ['aba', 'bab'];
const bar = [1, 2];
```

and then create this array:

```
result = [
{
  text: foo[0]
  number: bar[0]
},
{
  text: foo[1]
  number: bar[1]
}
]
```

Foo and bar will have equal lengths.

Comment: Will `foo` and `bar` always be the same length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your arrays have same length, you can use [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over each *item*, get the *item* and the *index* and then create the new array of objects setting the *text* to *item* and the *number* to `bar[index]`.

```js
const foo = ['aba', 'bab'];
const bar = [1, 2];

const mapped = foo.map((item, index) => ({text: item, number: bar[index]}));

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply map one of the array and use the second parameters of the mapping function, the index, to get the value for the other one:

```
var result = foo.map((value, index) => ({
     text: value, number: bar[index],
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solutin

```js
let result = [] ;
const foo = ['aba','bab']
const bar = [1,2]
for(let i = 0 ; i<foo.length;i++){
  result[i]={}
  result[i].text = foo[i] ; 
  result[i].number = bar[i];
}
console.log(result) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the are always the same length, you can do:

```
var foo = ['aba','bab']
var bar = [1,2]

function makeObjects(f, b) {
    return foo.map((o, i) => ({text: f[i], number: bar[i]}))
}

console.log(makeObjects(foo, bar))
// [{text: 'aba', number: 1}, {text: 'bab', number: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = ['aba','bab'];
var bar = [1,2];
var result = [];
function a(){
    for(var i=0;i<foo.length;i++){
        result[i] = { text: foo[i], number:bar[i]};
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

is this what you are looking for?